# How to remove CSS from header

Tags: javascript

I know how to add a css element to a header using JS but how do I remove one?

To add :

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css'; 
style.innerHtml = ".item {color:red}";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

My question is how can I remove the element, I tried

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(style);
```

It throws up an error, I want to remove the css and not throw an error if it doesn't exist.

Your help is most appreciated.

I do not want to use JQuery.

The actual solution based on Daniels that I used is :-

```
        var DeskTag = document.getElementById('style');

        if (DeskTag!=null) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(DeskTag);
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying your removal code works if it exists, but you are only getting the error when it doesn't exist?

Comment: You should be using `textContent`, not `innerhtml` (or even the correctly spelled `innerHTML`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give it an id and access it directly:

```
style.id = 'style-tag'
```

```
const styleTag = document.getElementById('style-tag');
if (!styleTag) return;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(styleTag);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I got it work using the method above, slightly different coding but if it hadn't been for the answer, I wouldn't have cracked it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is just as simple as you do the following:
instead of using .removeChild(style);

First let's simulate we add the style:

```
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css'; 
    style.innerhtml = ".item {color:red}";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Then let's remove it:

```
function removeStyle(){
  style.innerHTML = ""; // you just need to reset the style as it was: blank
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}
removeStyle();
```

If this doesn't work, I hope it gives you an idea of what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only the one 'style' tag, use

```
document.querySelector('style').remove()
```

in case there could be a bunch of them, add a class for each:

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = ".item {color:red}";
style.classList.add('style_to_delete')
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.querySelector('.style_to_delete').remove()
```